# How to get domains in Shadowsocks server log with Shadowsocks Android

Tags: android, logging

When I enable the domain sniffing settings (enabled by default) in Shadowrocket Android app, I can see domains in the server log.
However, with Shadowsocks Android, I only get IP addresses. How can I get the domains like Shadowrocket?

I'm expecting to get domains in Shadowsocks server log rather than IPs when using Shadowsocks Android.